# global variables not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Code in my application/libraries/globals.php is :

```
<?php
class Globals {
public function __construct($config = array()) {
foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
$data[$key] = $value;
}
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->vars($data);
}
}
?>
```

and in application/config/globals.php

```
 <?php

 $config['tmp2'] = "testing 2";
?>
```

and  in controller i am loading

```
        function aboutus()
{     
$autoload['libraries'] = array('globals');  
$this->load->view('aboutus.php',$data);
}
```

and in views called about.php:

```
 <?php 
 echo $tmp2;
 ?>
```

But global variables are not working in this. If i am lacking in any point then please tell me

Comment: do you get any error s?

Comment: no.. about.php view is working fine on front end... it is just not displaying value of $tmp2.

Comment: can you echo the value of $tmp2 in your controller ??

Answer (score 0):

Everything is looking fine. Kindly try to change library  file name from global.php to Global.php. Notice capital G

Answer (score 0):

So i tried replicating what you did here on my installation, and honestly i dont understand what you did in the globals library file initially... But to get the value like you said, add this to your controller just before you load the view

```
function aboutus()
{     
$autoload['libraries'] = array('globals');  
$my_config = $this->config->load('globals', true);
$data=array();
$data['tmp2'] = $this->config->item('tmp2', 'globals');
$this->load->view('aboutus.php',$data);
}
```

`$data` is an array of variables you are passing to the view, so after storing the config value in the `$data['tmp2']`, you can call it as `$tmp2` in your view.

All the best.